# Jquery UI 10.2 AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Just added the latest version to my site, however my .renderitem breaks
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined "

Do I assume its been replaced\ or whats the work around?

```
 $(function() {
                $("#MainSearch").autocomplete({
                        source: "@Url.Action("ClientSearch","Schedule")",
                        minLength: 3,
                        select: function(event, ui) {

                            $("#MainSearch").val(ui.item.ClientName);
                            $("#mainSearchId").val(ui.item.ClientId);

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                ).data("autocomplete")
                    ._renderItem = function(ul, client) {
                        return $("<li></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", client)
                            .append("<a>" + client.FullName + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    };


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to rename

```
.data("uiAutocomplete")
```